# Developing Top AppBar for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, appbar

I am developing a simple application for windows 8. And now I want to modify the top app bar( i.e it should not look like bottom app bar) and I want it to work much better than only showing the default icons(like navigation job). I want to add my icons of different sizes(length).yes similar to those of weather app or travel app. But I am unable to find any good reference to start with. please help, from where I should start doing it. and whether is it possible to modify the app bar. please guide. note: I am developing app in javascript

Answer (score 2):

Your very basic top appbar can be implemented using the following  HTML:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{layout:'custom',placement:'top'}">
    <!-- your custom top bar content goes here -->
</div>
```

From inside the `div`, you can add anything to your hearts content, even AppBarCommands.  Don't forget to initialize all win controls:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
         WinJS.UI.processAll();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: the  key that allow that here is actually the layout:'custom' option. If that is not specified, it will not render the custom html

Answer (score 1):

[Quickstart: adding an app bar with custom content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780658.aspx)

Comment: I have already studied it. But it is not enough to implement the navigation bar. i am kind of beginner in this field. Any Other help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read following article, you'll get lot's of good tips

[31 Days of Windows 8 | Day #4: New Controls](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/04/31-days-of-windows-8-day-4-new-controls)

Comment: thank you for suggestion. but I am developing app in javascript. Clark Sell have not described that in detail. any other suggestion ?